# rails: What happens when two web servers are specified in a Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, unicorn, puma, gemfile

If two web servers (say puma and unicorn) are specified
in the Gemfile, which one gets precedence?

I tried doing this myself but realized I was on windows with not much ruby support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long Answer with example:

1. you created app with rails 5.0.0, you get puma webserver by default.
2. you install unicorn gem. and you start the server by `rails server` still your server is puma. why ? because `config/puma.rb` file which generated with `rails new application-name` .
3. To start unicorn server you have to created one file for unicorn in config folder.
4. To start unicorn server you have to execute command like this `unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` in your terminal. 
   I think this is the answer of your question.

Short answer:

You have tell rails explicitly which webserver you have to run. Rails will not decide which to run (in case of multiple web server).

I hope this clear your doubts.
Cheers